# Quantize MobileFaceNet with TFLITE failed

Tags: face-recognition, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to find a solution to run face recognition on AI camera. And found that [MobileFacenet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07573) ([code from sirius-ai](https://github.com/sirius-ai/MobileFaceNet_TF/)) is great as a light model!

I succeed to convert to TFLITE with F32 format with good accuracy.
However when I failed when quantized to uint8 with the following command:

```
tflite_convert --output_file tf-lite/MobileFacenet_uint8_128.tflite 
--graph_def_file tf-lite/MobileFacenet.pb 
--input_arrays "input" 
--input_shapes "1,112,112,3" 
--output_arrays output 
--output_format TFLITE 
--mean_values 128 
--std_dev_values 127.5 
--default_ranges_min 0 
--default_ranges_max 255 
--inference_type QUANTIZED_UINT8 
--inference_input_type QUANTIZED_UINT8
```

[This thread](https://github.com/sirius-ai/MobileFaceNet_TF/issues/46) help to convert to TFLITE, but not talking about the quantization.
Could anyone provide some suggestions? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tflite_convert` requires either `--saved_model_dir` or `--keras_model_file` to be defined. When using TF2.x, you should use `--enable_v1_converter` if you want to convert to quantized tflite from frozen graph.

EDIT:

What you are currently doing is called "dummy quantization", which can be used to test the inference timings of the quantized network. To properly quantize the network, min/max information of layers should be injected into it with fake quant nodes.

Please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/crypt3lx2k/cec6ad66b948fe0e77a7b1e6d2205bf4) for example codes on how to do it. [This blog post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/mobile-inference-b943dc99e29b) also has some information on quantization aware training.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. i am using TF1.12, and use --graph_def_file tf-lite/MobileFacenet.pb file to convert. I thought pb file and saved model should both suppported by TF?

Comment: They should be. What is the exact error message you get when trying to convert?

Comment: I did not get error message, but the result is incorrect. I simply compare two face images, get the encoding of MobileFacenet.pb, and converted *.tflite. and calculate eu distance to verify the output. For faces of the same person, the distance should be smaller than faces of different person. The output of *.pb or using   --post_training_quantize 1 to convert to *.tflite is ok. But when convert to uint8 with the above command, the result is incorrect.

Comment: What you are currently doing is called "dummy quantization", which can be used to test the inference timings of the quantized network. To properly quantize the network, min/max information of layers should be injected into it with fake quant nodes.


Please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/crypt3lx2k/cec6ad66b948fe0e77a7b1e6d2205bf4) for example codes on how to do it.

[This blog post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/mobile-inference-b943dc99e29b) also has some information on quantization aware training.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will go with Quantization Aware Training.

Comment: You're welcome. I added my previous comment also to the answer.

Comment: Hi @sakumoli, I followed the suggest to add fake quant but failed. Could you help check this post as well? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108767/create-training-graph-failed-when-converted-mobilefacenet-to-quantize-aware-mo