# create_training_graph() failed when converted MobileFacenet to quantize-aware model with TF-lite

Tags: tensorflow, quantization, tensorflow-lite, quantization-aware-training

I am trying to quantize [MobileFacenet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27880) ([code from sirius-ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804754/quantize-mobilefacenet-with-tflite-failed)) according to the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804754/quantize-mobilefacenet-with-tflite-failed)
and I think I met the same issue as [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27880)

When I add `tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph()` into training graph 
(train_nets.py ln.187: before `train_op = train(...)` or in `train()` utils/common.py ln.38 before gradients)

It did not add quantize-aware ops into the graph to collect dynamic range max\min.

I assume that I should see some additional nodes in tensorboard, but I did not, thus I think I did not successfully add quantize-aware ops in training graph.
And I try to trace tensorflow, found that I got nothing with _FindLayersToQuantize().

However when I add `tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph()` to refine the training graph. I can see some quantize-aware ops as act_quant...
Since I did not add ops in training graph successfully, I have no weights to load in eval graph.
Thus I got some error message as

```
Key MobileFaceNet/Logits/LinearConv1x1/act_quant/max not found in checkpoint
```

or

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value MobileFaceNet/Logits/LinearConv1x1/act_quant/max
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? or how to get quantized MobileFacenet with good accuracy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H,

Unfortunately, the contrib/quantize tool is now deprecated. It won't be able to support newer models, and we are not working on it anymore.

If you are interested in QAT, I would recommend trying the new [TF/Keras QAT API](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/04/quantization-aware-training-with-tensorflow-model-optimization-toolkit.html). We are actively developing that and providing support for it.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I use post training integer quantization instead.

Comment: Will try Keras QAT API to see if it helps the accuracy. Thanks!